# Intellij: What causes a dark green inspection highlight?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

After searching forums and stackoverflow I can't see to figure out what this inspection highlight is trying to alert me to:

[image]

Selecting/hovering over the highlighted text returns nothing besides the standard context actions.

Originally these variables were declared and instantiated before the constructor. **(ACTIONS TAKEN TO REPRODUCE) When I used the context action "Move initialization to constructor", the initializations in the constructor are highlighted dark green. See attached img.**

Anyone know what's going on here?

example:

```java
public class HoaQueueEditorDialog extends ListDialogBase implements Mutable {

    private static final String SAVE = "Save";
    private static final String CANCEL = "Cancel";
    private static final String CHAR_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String[] COL_NAMES = {"Workflow Step Name"};
    private static final Color NORM_BACKGROUND = TRexUIManager.getColor(TRexUIManager.CONTENT_BACKGROUND);
    private static final Color NORM_FOREGROUND = Color.black;
    private static final int[] COL_WIDTHS = {325};
    private static final ArrayList<AppOptionsUtil.WorkflowStepInfo> SUPPORTED_STEPS_LIST = AppOptionsUtil.getDisplayHoaInfoWfStepsSupportedList();

    // UI Elements
    private TButton saveButton;
    private TButton cancelButton;
    private JPanel parentPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanelRight;
    private JPanel buttonPanelLeft;

    // Stores the data necessary to build a table row and it's corresponding checkbox object.
    protected HashMap<AppOptionsUtil.WorkflowStepInfo, TCheckBox> checkBoxMap;

    private TTable wfQueuesTable;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    private TChangeListener changeListener = null;

    private boolean escKeyPressedInsideYesNoCancel = false;

    private String originalAppOptionValues = null;
    private String returnAppOptionValues = null;

    public HoaQueueEditorDialog() {
        try {
            this.tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{}}, COL_NAMES);
            this.wfQueuesTable = new TTable();
            wfQueuesTable.setModel(tableModel);
            wfQueuesTable.setBackground(NORM_BACKGROUND);
            wfQueuesTable.setRowHeight(42);
            wfQueuesTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new DocumentTableSelectionListener());

            init();
            initMVC();
            this.setResizable(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            TRexToolkit.showErrorMessage("Error initializing Document Print Screen.", "Error", ex);
        }
        buttonPanelLeft = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(LEFT));
        buttonPanelRight = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(RIGHT));
        parentPanel = new JPanel();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] as text, formatted as code, within the question itself?

Comment: @slaw added code however I believe the reproducible part is related to use the context actions of moving the instantiations to the constructor. As I create more objects and use the context action "Move initializer to constructor" the initialized code moved to the constructor is highlighted green.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is highlighting the changes it made when you invoked the `Move initialization to constructor` intention. Because the changes are quite far away from the cursor, you might not see them otherwise. Pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> will remove the highlighting.